# ошибка при создании мода для майнкрафта на fabric1

Tags: java, minecraft

Я учусь создавать мод на fabricmc, с помощью гайда с ютуба и я хотел создать предмет (ну или как я понял код для создания предметов) и там получается две функции (ну или переменные не знаю). Как объяснялось одна для создания предмета,а другая для создания группы предмета.
вот код который был:

```
    private static Item registerItem(String id, Item item) { return Registry.register(Registries.ITEM, new Identifier(ExampleMod.MOD_ID, id), item ); }
    private static Item registerItem(String id, Item item, ItemGroup itemGroup) {
        Item returnItem = Registry.register(Registries.ITEM, new Identifier(ExampleMod.MOD_ID, id), item );
        ItemGroupEvents.modifyEntriesEvent(itemGroup).register(entries -> entries.add(returnItem));


        return returnItem;
    }
```

Ошибка выходит такая:

```
'modifyEntriesEvent(net.minecraft.registry.RegistryKey<net.minecraft.item.ItemGroup>)' in 'net.fabricmc.fabric.api.itemgroup.v1.ItemGroupEvents' cannot be applied to '(net.minecraft.item.ItemGroup)'
```

(если что то ошибку выдает на эту строку:

```
ItemGroupEvents.modifyEntriesEvent(itemGroup).register(entries -> entries.add(returnItem));
                                   ^
```

Помогите решить эту проблему на версии 1.20.4

Comment: Попробуйте заменить `registerItem(String id, Item item, ItemGroup itemGroup)` на `registerItem(String id, Item item, RegistryKey<ItemGroup> itemGroup)`